# MULTIPLE CRITERIA TABLE JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a table listing clothing items (shirt, trousers, etc) named . Each item is identified with a unique CLOTHING.CLOTHING_ID. So a blue shirt  is 01, a flowery shirt is 12 and jeans are 07 say.

I have a second table identifying outfits with a column for shirts, for trousers, shoes etc. For example 
Outfit 1: shirt 01, trousers 07 (i.e. blue shirt with jeans)
Outfit 2: shirt 12, trousers 07 (so flowery shirt with jeans).

This table is named  and each outfit is unique with OUTFIT_LIST.OUTFIT_ID.

I want to produce a select statement that will list each outfit's contents, i.e. find the clothing specified in Outfit 1.

Any help would be very much appreciated, and apologies in advance if I am missing a very simple solution. I have been playing with JOINS of all descriptions and CONCATS and so on with now luck - I am very new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your `outfit` table is a one-to-many relationship between the `outfit_id` and the `clothing_id` - e.g.

```
outfit_id | clothing_id

        1 |           1
        1 |           7
        2 |           1
        2 |          12
```

This allows you to add any number of items to an outfit - whether it's a suit, a jacket, a dress, etc. etc.

Then to select items for an outfit is very easy:

```
SELECT clothing_id FROM outfit WHERE outfit_id = ?
```

In my example above, `outfit_id` of `1` would return `1,7` - i.e. a blue shirt and jeans.

Or to get the clothing item names:

```
SELECT c.name FROM clothing c JOIN outfits o ON c.clothing_id=o.clothing_id
WHERE o.outfit_id = ?
```

Again, in my example above, `outfit_id` of `1` would return `blue shirt, jeans`.

Comment: @Mavman - does "nearly there" mean solved or you need more help?

Comment: Thanks @amaidment
I'm struggling with a cross page list of outfits that are followed by their clothing contents

Comment: @Mavman - sorry, I don't understand your comment. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: no need to apologise as I am not explaining myself very well. 

My aim is to have a list of the names of the Outfits andlongside them the clothing therin: Outfit 1, Blue shirt, jeans; Outfit 2, Red shirt, moleskins, etc

Comment: @Mavman - but I would have thought that is an issue for the client program, not for the relational database?

Comment: thank you both so much for your help and my apologies for not responding sooner but I am in the middle of moving house. I shall be having a go at finishing this off next week. Till then...